# Regex only retrieves the first necessary element but not all of them

Tags: .net, regex

Can anybody help me with retrieving some elements from the following example text:

```
sdfaasdflj asdfjl;a 
AB-12/34 BC-/85 CD-//8 DD-77
DE-78/9
EE-78-98
asdf; asdjf
```

It is necessary to get the following elements:
AB-12/34, BC-/85, CD-//8, DD-77, DE-78/9

When I'm using a regular expression like this:

```
\s*(?<elements>\b[A-Z]{2}-[/0-9]+\b)
```

everything works fine - all the necessary elements are being retrieved (except for the EE element are amonth them, but it doesn't matter).
The problem is that this line is a part of a more complex regex, so when I'm trying to apply a regex like this:

```
(?s).*\sas.*?
\s*(?<elements>\b[A-Z]{2}-[/0-9]+\b)*.*
.*as
```

It only returns me just the first AB-12/34 element and nothing else.
How to correct the regex to get all the elements? TIA.

Comment: Do you want each of the elements in a seperate capture group, or all of them together in one? And how do you use this Regex in your program?

Comment: I'm going to use it like this:

...
var m = Regex.Match(txtInput.Text, txtPattern.Text);
if (m.Success)
{
    var elements = m.Groups["elements"];
    var captures = elements.Captures;
    foreach (Capture capture in captures)
    {
        lstResults.Items.Add(capture.Value);
    }
}
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the block `"(?<elements>\b[A-Z]{2}-[/0-9]+\b)*"` multiple times in your example, you need to include the whitespace in it. I.e.:

```
"(?<elements>\s*\b[A-Z]{2}-[/0-9]+\b)*"
```

If you do not want to capture it, try `""(?:\s*(?<elements>\b[A-Z]{2}-[/0-9]+\b))*"`. I am not sure how the named capture group, inside a non-capturing group will work, though. =)

Comment: A capturing group inside a non-capturing group works fine.  In .NET you can use a CaptureCollection to retrieve all the matches, e.g.: `theMatch.Groups["elements"].Captures`